# How can i write the AWS lamda unit test cases in scala?

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

How we can implement the unit test cases for aws lamda serverless.
My code is

```
    object Test1 extends RequestHandler[APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent] with ResponseObjProcess {


  override def handleRequest(input: APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, context: Context): APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent = {
    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
    val gson = new Gson

    val requestHttpMethod = input.getHttpMethod
    val requestBody = input.getBody
    val requestHeaders = input.getHeaders
    val requestPath = input.getPath
    val requestPathParameters = input.getPathParameters
    val requestQueryStringParameters = input.getQueryStringParameters
    val parsedBody = JSON.parseFull(requestBody).getOrElse(0).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
    println(" parsedBody is:: " + parsedBody)

    val active = parsedBody.get("active").getOrElse("false")
    val created = parsedBody.get("created").getOrElse("0").toLong
    val updated = parsedBody.get("updated").getOrElse("0").toLong

    requestHttpMethod match {
      case "PUT" =>
        println(" PUT Request method ")
        //  insertRecords("alert_summary_report", requestBody)
        response.setStatusCode(200)
        response.setBody(gson.toJson("PUT"))
      case _ =>
        println("")
        response.setStatusCode(400)
        response.setBody(gson.toJson("None"))

    }
    response
  }
}
```

And I tried to implement unit test cases for the above code.
Below code is:

```
test("testing record success case") {

    var request = new APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent();
    request.setHttpMethod(Constants.PUTREQUESTMETHOD)

    DELETEREQUESTBODY.put("id", "")

    request.setBody(EMPTYREQUESTBODY)
    request.setPathParameters(DELETEREQUESTBODY)

    println(s"body = ${request.getBody}")
    println(s"headers = ${request.getHeaders}")

    val response = ProxyRequestMain.handleRequest(subject, testContext)
    val assertEqual = response.getStatusCode.equals(200)
    assertEqual
  }
```

Actually, I'm getting **response.getStatusCode=400** bad requests but test case passed how can I write handle this.

Comment: Can you show us the unit test code you've got at the moment and what's wrong with it?

Comment: It's just the same way when you test non-Lambda code -- pass a known input and assert for its result.

Comment: So, what was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: @Dima I have updated my code. Can you please check it

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at your test code and it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with your assertions. I think you might have mixed quite a few things. In the code as it currently stands, you have a `val`, not assertion. I'd encourage you to have a look at the relevant docs and research the options available to you:

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers